# Stripe iOS integration server side code

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I have been playing around with the Stripe SDK and API and I am a little confused. I have a very simple use case. I want to use the built in STPAddCardViewController and STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate to save card information that a user puts in. We also need to charge the card based on the credit card the user created. We have a unique identifier for each user when they create an account and any user that has access to our app does need to create an account. What is the best way to do this?

We also aren’t able to get the card information (STPCardParams) that a user selects from the STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate. How would we do that?

The part that I am having the most trouble with is the server side piece. I know Stripe gives example code for this but I haven’t been able to get it to work for us. We are using a backend as a service for our app so don’t use code to create our server. Is there any simple code that we can deploy that allows us to pass the card information, our Stripe API key, a charge amount, and a currency to a server (on heroku for example), and just have that server charge the card for us? I don’t think this is that hard to do and it seems like it can be pretty cookie cutter for everyone who is using stripe. If this is the case, does anybody have the code for this? Is it possible to use stripe without server side code?

Comment: there is a library created in Swift for Vapor server if you are interested. https://github.com/vapor-community/stripe

Comment: That is exactly what I need! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you looked into this library? Is it production ready?

Comment: It's production ready. More info on vapor.codes and on slack.qutheory.io in the `help` group